# Different versions of XCode and splash screen laying in Resources vs Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have updated Cordova from some old version to 6.3.0. Cordova generates an XCode project that I can compile from XCode.

With the old version of Cordova, as what I see, splash screens files were put inside `Resources/splash` folder and it worked.

Now, with Cordova 6.3.0 I need them to be put inside `Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage` folder. If the files are inside `Resources/splash`, as used to be before Cordova upgrade, they are ignored and default ones are used.

I suppose this new structure is dictated by new XCode and is supported by new Cordova.

The question is how XCode knows where to look for splash screens images? Is it that version of XCode project is mentioned somewhere when it's generated by Cordova?